# Tint of UIBarButtonItem doesn't match color I set

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor, tint

The background color for my view in RGB format is 
R:  111/255
G:  209/255
B:  229/255

I tried setting the tint of the UIBarButtonItem using:

```
CGFloat nRed=111.0/255.0;
CGFloat nGreen=209.0/255.0;
CGFloat nBlue=229/255.0;
UIColor *myColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nBlue blue:nGreen alpha:1];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:myColor];
```

The color does change for all the UIBarButtonItems I have in the project...but it is still noticeably different from the color of my background.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the name of the button you're trying to change? '[UIBarButtonItem appearance]' applies the settings to all. Is it leftBarButtonItem, rightBarButtonItem, or backBarbuttonItem?

Comment: as for the color difference, I always specify a float for my values, like so: nBlue = 229.0f/255.0f, instead of just the numbers. Works for me.

Comment: you are passing nBlue to green and nGreen to blue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the `appearance` method.  Just do this:

```
//Suppose you have a variable barButtonItem
barButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: I called appearance method because I am using navigation controllers that auto add in UIBarButtonItems spread across several views, and didn't want to go through and set tintColor property for each one.